# Two routers at home, is there any intrinsic property that could differentiate networks?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, windows-media-player

I have two routers at home. I shall call them A and B. Both are capable of both wired and wireless connections. I have disabled wireless features on A, and connected B's uplink to A's downlink.

I did not connect A's downlink to B's downink, because I wanted to use B's wireless connections, and I want all computers connected either to A or to B to be in the same network. B has something called "hub-mode". So I set it.

All computers seem to have no problem in connecting to the Internet. All computers are assigned with IPv4 addresses in the same private C class range from A. All can access each other using Windows network (or Samba) or ping each other by IP address without any problem.

The problem is that for some specific protocols, computers connected to B do not find those connected to A. For example, if I "ping-by-host-name" a computer which is connected to A from a computer which is connected to B, it fails. Also, Windows Media Player's library sharing does not find each other when they are connected to a different router. (If only IPv4 is enabled, it is so. If IPv6 is enabled, only computers on wired connection seem to be found.) This does not seem to be Windows' problem, because it was also happened with DLNA clients on my two Android devices.

So, what I am wondering is if there is any intrinsic factor that could make softwares think computers connected to A and computers connected to B are in different networks. Their IPv4 addresses are all in the same C class, and their subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`. With my shallow knowledge I cannot think of any reason why they are not considered in the same network. They If there is no such thing, I am thinking about buying a different router for B, because it might be a specific problem of B's firmware.

===Added details===

I could not find any multicasting or such settings either in A nor B. I have not enabled any feature that might affect the traffic (such as "worm virus detection")

If I do not use the "hub-mode" of B, but just connect A's downlink to B's downlink, B seems to be working as a hub. In this mode, wireless features seem to be automatically disabled and I cannot access the administration web page of B. The interest thing is, in this state, Windows Media Player finds each other in another router. But I cannot use this mode, because I want wireless connections, too.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I have added the names of routers. So, the problems I have are not supposed to happen when using two routers, if "the settings are correct"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the WAN port, use one of the LAN ports on the secondary router B. Also, disable DHCP and point the DNS, router and gateway settings to router A's IP address if you can. Let me know what happens. I have an identical setup.

Comment: Well, yes, that’s basically the universal solution. This will also provide wireless access as desired. I guess the OP’s “Hub Mode”, whatever that may be, doesn’t have the desired effect.

Comment: It seems like otherwise your router B's WAN uplink port puts computers on a separate vlan, and you can only edit vlans with command line access (unlikely to work) or custom firmware. Multicast traffic is not forwarded between vlans or subnets without special software to forward it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mr Jeremiah Barrar. Doing so solves the problem but then Wi-Fi on B is also disabled (as described in my "added details"). I need to use Wi-Fi on B. Perhaps I have to buy a new router for B.

Comment: That is very strange. I would try another router, such as linksys E2500. Custom firmware may help also, I use the E2500 with Tomato: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29 Here are some downloads: http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26RT-N/build5x-128-EN/